# Postgres constraint where col1 cannot be identical to col2

Tags: postgresql, constraints

for example,

if col1 is to represent **player 1**,
and col2 is to represent **player 2**,

if the two are to play with each other, **player 2** cannot be the same player as **player 1**.

I don't want to add a constraint where these two players only get to play with each other once, I just want that constraint to be applied for each individual row.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you have described, this seems like a simple check constraint:

```
alter table the_table
   constraint different_players
   check (player_1 <> player_2);
```

If those columns can contain NULL values, then maybe:

```
alter table the_table
   constraint different_players
   check (player_1 is distinct from player_2);
```